# Why am I still getting retainCount=1, after releasing my objects

Tags: ios, objective-c

Why am I still getting `retainCount = 1`, after releasing my objects.

This is my code. Can any one help me to fix this:

```
    newsDetail *newsdetails = [[newsDetail alloc] initWithNibName:@"newsDetail" bundle:nil];
    [newsdetails insertSomeData];

    NSLog(@"Object Count in memmory = %d",[newsdetails retainCount]);

    [self.view addSubview:newsdetails.view];
    NSLog(@"Object Count in memmory = %d",[newsdetails retainCount]);

    [newsdetails release];
    NSLog(@"Object Count in memmory = %d",[newsdetails retainCount]);
```

........

```
2011-09-20 10:26:10.208 memmory[1977:207] Object Count in memmory = 1
2011-09-20 10:26:10.212 memmory[1977:207] Object Count in memmory = 1
2011-09-20 10:26:10.213 memmory[1977:207] Object Count in memmory = 1
```

Comment: retainCount is useless. Don't call it.  retainCount can never return 0.

Answer (score 0):

The alloced object is retained, hence retain = 1; addSubview increases retain count by one, you decrease the retain by one in release call.

Comment: How come the output is 1, 1, 1 then? Shouldn't it be 1, 2, 1 if you are telling the truth?

Comment: yes, but you are printing retainCount of newstedail, rather than newsdetail.view

Comment: the added subview is released when the self.view gets released. Your implementation is correct, you have one alloc and one release. If you want check for leaks, use Instruments, not retainCount. See the docs (NSObject Class Reference)[http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html]

Comment: @mja: Ahh, that explains. I also understands now :) Thank you!

Comment: Absolute retain counts are meaningless (which is also why the `retainCount` method is useless).  You either increase or decrease the retain count.

Answer (score -1):

When you add a view as a subview somewhere then this view is retained.